# Convert Sentence case string

Tags: php

i want ask how to Convert Sentence case string in PHP

i have variable string

```
$sring = "hello world,world,world heloo";
```

i want convert Sentence case per "," to

```
$string = "Hello World,World,World Heloo";
```

how to make this
please help all experts

Comment: Shouldn't the first and last part be "Hello world" and "World heloo" as there is no comma?

Comment: Why the javascript tag? Where are you stuck with this task?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uppercase each word after a comma

```php
<?php
$sring = "hello world,world,world heloo";
echo ucwords(strtolower($sring), '\',');
```

**UPDATE**:
I have added space to the delimiter.

```php
<?php
$sring = "hello world,world,world heloo";
echo ucwords(strtolower($sring), '\', ');
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use **ucwords** function

```
<?php
    echo ucwords("hello,world", ",");
 ?>
```

Comment: Not if OP actually wants `Hello World` and `World Heloo` as output

Comment: Try `", "` on the delims. It's not too helpful to cherry-pick an example. Best to use OP's example so you can easily show it works (or not). But yeah, question is off-topic so this should be closed out.